# Finding the limit of a sequence containing a factorial $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty}\frac{n^3-n^2-2}{n!}.$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I have the limit $$\lim \limits_{n \to \infty}\frac{n^3-n^2-2}{n!}.$$ I am able to convert it into the form $$\lim \limits_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{\frac{n!}{n^3}}$$ but am stuck on how to solve $$\lim \limits_{n \to \infty}\frac{n!}{n^3}.$$ I know that $n!$ grows at a much larger rate than $n^3$ but am unsure how to express this in mathematical terms.

Comment: $n! \ge n(n - 1)(n - 2)(n - 3) = n^4 + \text{ errors}$ once $n \ge 4$.

Comment: and what is $x$? has it some connection to $n$?

Comment: Sorry, formatted incorrectly. x is not a variable that is part of this question.

Comment: You may use that for large enough $n$ one has $n!>e^n$ (*this is an* **incredibly** *loose comparison.  for a tighter comparison, look up sterling's approximation*) and so compare to the related limits $\frac{n^3-n^2-2}{e^n}$ and $\frac{e^n}{n^3}$.  You should know that exponentials are a much faster growing variety than polynomials are.  Also an option is to use L'Hopital's rule, (*why I suggested comparison to $e^n$*)

Comment: Factorials grow faster than polynomials.  And $\frac {1}{\frac {n!}{n^3}} = \frac {n^3}{n!}$ you have that inverted.

Comment: To understand $\displaystyle\frac{n!}{n^3}$ rewrite it as $\displaystyle\left(\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)}{n^3}\right)(n-3)!$ and recognize that the first factor $\to 1$ and the second factor $\to \infty$ as $n\to \infty$.

Comment: @Cosmic Please remember that you can choose an answer among the given if the OP is solved, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 10):

Note that for $n$ large the expression is positive and $n!>n^4$ (you can prove easily a part this two assumptions) then

$$0\le\frac{n^3-n^2-2}{n!}\le\frac{n^3-n^2-2}{n^4}=\frac1{n}-\frac1{n^2}-\frac2{n^4}\to 0$$

thus for [squeeze theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem)

$$\lim \limits_{n \to \infty}\frac{n^3-n^2-2}{n!}=0$$

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2678602/456510

Comment: @MathLover Dear MathLover, Thanks for your kind words, I indeed saw your OP and I've noticed that it has received a lot of good aswers, in praticular from Jack and Paramanand Singh two of the most quoted and skilled people here on MSE. I will take  alook and I'll come for a feedback to you. Bye

Answer (score 4):

### Hint

$$\frac{n^3-n^2-2}{n!}=\frac{1}{(n-3)!}+\frac{2}{(n-2)!}-\frac{2}{n!}$$

Answer (score 3):

**Another hint**:

Note first that $\;u_n\sim_\infty\dfrac{n^3}{n!}$, so

$$\frac{u_{n+1}}{u_n}\sim_\infty \biggl(\frac{n+1}n\biggr)^3\frac1{n+1}\sim_\infty \frac1{n+1}\to 0.$$

Answer (score 0):

As other answers have noted, there are plenty of fancy ways to show the limit you want to show. But remember, *you can always go back to the definition of a limit* and work from there. If we wish to show that

$$\lim \limits_{n \to \infty}\frac{n!}{n^3}$$

goes to infinity, we must show that for any choice of lower bound $L$ there exists an integer $m$ such that $m<n$ implies that $L<\frac{n!}{n^3}$

We begin by noting that $1 < \frac{(n)(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)}{n^3}$ for all $n>6$.  (Can you prove this fact?)

Therefore, for our $m$ we can choose $L+4$ or $6$, whichever is larger, and we have

$$\frac{n!}{n^3} = (\frac{(n)(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)}{n^3})(n-4)(...) $$

if $n>m$ then we have the first part being greater than one, the $(n-4)$ part being greater than $L$, and the $(...)$ part being greater than one, so we can conclude that the whole product is greater than $L$, and we're done.

Going back to the definition is tedious but it gets the job done, and it's good practice.